# Radio button in JSF doesn't set value properly

Tags: jsf

My JSF radio button doesn't work and I don't really know why. Here' some code:

```
        <h:selectOneRadio value="#{jSFDatabase.type}">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="Database" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Webservice" />
        </h:selectOneRadio>

        <h:outputLabel value="#{jSFDatabase.type }" />
```

If I click the other radio button the value is still 0 (default). Why is this code not working? The Getter and Setter are here:

```
public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}
```

How can I fix that issue?

Comment: What would be the scope of `jSFDatabase`? Are you posting the form after changing the selection?

Comment: Do you mean a button or something else? No I don't do that how shoud I change the code?

Comment: You would need to either use a `<h:commandButton>` to post the form and re-render the page, or use `<f:ajax>` to explicitly re-render a region of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to either use `<f:ajax />` to re-render the affected regions of the page, or, if you prefer not to use AJAX, post the form. Otherwise, the data won't be updated.

For example, you could do this:

```
    <h:selectOneRadio value="#{jSFDatabase.type}">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="Database" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Webservice" />
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="myValue" />
    </h:selectOneRadio>

    <h:outputLabel id="myValue" value="#{jSFDatabase.type }" />
```

See:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html
https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-button-and-commandbutton-example/